# How to vertically align a checkbox with its label in MaterializeCSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox, materialize

Is there any way to vertically align (center) a checkbox and its label in MaterializeCSS? [This fiddle demonstrates the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/wittski/t8EGn/12506/#run) - I'd like the checkbox to be vertically centered relative to the blue box. If you remove materialize from the fiddle and use vanilla HTML/CSS it works.

Thank you!!

**Materialize version:** 0.100.2

**HTML:**

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input id="myinput" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="myinput">
      <div class="label-content">         
      Label Text
      </div></label>
  </div></form>
```

**CSS:**

```
label {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.label-content {
   height:100px;
   background-color:aliceblue;
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `top:50%` and some negative margin(*half of the element height*) to the `:before` and `:after` pseudo class of label.

```
.parent [type="checkbox"]+label:before,
.parent [type="checkbox"]:not(.filled-in)+label:after {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -9px;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/t8EGn/12507/)**